# Adding values from a for loop inside an object with a custom structure

Tags: javascript

Here is the object structure I need:

```
var states = {
    'countryCode1' : { 'stateCode1' : 'stateName1', 'stateCode2' : 'stateName2', .... }
    'countryCode2' : { 'stateCode1' : 'stateName1', 'stateCode2' : 'stateName2', .... }
    .................................
};
```

From this loop, where I have separate values for countryCode, stateCode and stateName, how can I build an object with the above structure?

```
for (var loop = 0; loop < stateLineArray.length; loop++) {

    lineArray = stateLineArray[loop].split(":");
    countryCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[0]);
    stateCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[1]);
    stateName = this.TrimString(lineArray[2]);

    // How can I add the values countryCode, stateCode and stateName in the states object, respecting it's structure?

    // Spmething like this:
    states[countryCode] = ....;

}
```

Any ideas?

Here is the structure of stateLineArray:

```
var stateLineArray = '\
Antigua and Barbuda:Antigua:Antigua|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Barbuda:Barbuda|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Redonda:Redonda|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Saint George:Saint George|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Saint John:Saint John|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Saint Mary:Saint Mary|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Saint Paul:Saint Paul|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Saint Peter:Saint Peter|\
Antigua and Barbuda:Saint Philip:Saint Philip|\
Argentina:Buenos Aires:Buenos Aires|\
Argentina:Catamarca:Catamarca|\
Argentina:Chaco:Chaco|\
Argentina:Chubut:Chubut|\
Argentina:Ciudad de Buenos Aires:Ciudad de Buenos Aires|\
Argentina:Córdoba:Córdoba|\
Argentina:Corrientes:Corrientes|\
Argentina:Entre Ríos:Entre Ríos|\
Argentina:Formosa:Formosa|\
Argentina:Jujuy:Jujuy|\
Argentina:La Pampa:La Pampa|\
Argentina:La Rioja:La Rioja|\
Argentina:Mendoza:Mendoza|\
Argentina:Misiones:Misiones|\
Argentina:Neuquen:Neuquen|\
Argentina:Río Negro:Río Negro|\
Argentina:Salta:Salta|\
Argentina:San Juan:San Juan|\
Argentina:San Luis:San Luis|\
Argentina:Santa Cruz:Santa Cruz|\
Argentina:Santa Fé:Santa Fé|\
Argentina:Santiago del Estero:Santiago del Estero|\
Argentina:Tierra del Fuego:Tierra del Fuego|\
Argentina:Tucuman:Tucuman|\
Bahamas:Abaco:Abaco|\
Bahamas:Acklins and Crooked Islands:Acklins and Crooked Islands|\
Bahamas:Andros Island:Andros Island|\
Bahamas:Bimini:Bimini|\
Bahamas:Cat Island:Cat Island|\
Bahamas:Eleuthera:Eleuthera|\
......'
```

Thank you!

Comment: `TrimString` where did that function come from? also what is `this` and why do you even need it?

Comment: That's not an array...

Comment: Just ignore the trimstring... I use it to split the stateLineArray and get individual values for countryCode, stateCode and stateName

Comment: @DanyD -- We can't just ignore extremely relevant parts of code. Do they return the correct values?

Comment: My mistake in not posting the question in a more general way. The ideea is... could I get 3 distinct values generated from a for loop inside an object and keep the desired structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var states = []

var stateLineArray = stateLineArray.split("|\\");

for (var loop = 0; loop < stateLineArray.length; loop++) {

    lineArray = stateLineArray[loop].replace("\\", "", split(":"));
    countryCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[0]);
    stateCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[1]);
    stateName = this.TrimString(lineArray[2]);

    if (typeof(states[countryCode]) == 'undefined') {

         states[countryCode] = [];

    }

    states[countryCode][statecode] = stateName;

}
```

Comment: This would result in an object that looks like the following: `states={ countryCode: { stateCode: 'Eleuthera (last stateName)' } }` because of the use of literal names. Only a single property is created at each level, and reused over and over. You need to use bracket-style notation instead: `states[countryCode][stateCode]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `trimstring` returns what it should (as OP says), this should do the trick:

```
lineArray = stateLineArray[loop].split(":");
countryCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[0]);
stateCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[1]);
stateName = this.TrimString(lineArray[2]);

var obj = { stateCode : stateCode, stateName : stateName };
states[countryCode] = obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to create a new object to hold each countryCode if it is not yet defined.  Note that I have assumed that each stateCode is unique.

```
var states = {};
for (var loop = 0; loop < stateLineArray.length; loop++) {

    lineArray = stateLineArray[loop].split(":");
    countryCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[0]);
    stateCode = this.TrimString(lineArray[1]);
    stateName = this.TrimString(lineArray[2]);

    // How can I add the values countryCode, stateCode and stateName in the states object, respecting it's structure?

    states[countryCode] = states[countryCode] || {};  //create new object if it does not exist
    states[countryCode][stateCode] = stateName;
}
```